# cómo saber números repetidos de un array por el orden que los va encontrando?

Tags: java, array

He intentado resolver esto de esta manera:

```
int array[]={1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5};
int duplicados[];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
  if(array[i]==array[j]{
    duplicados[i]=array[i];
}
}
}
```

pero los introduce por orden desde el inicio, yo quiero introducirlos por el primero que encuentre. Es decir algo similar a ésto:

[1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5]  ==>  [4, 3, 1, 5]

Si primero encuentra el 4 repetido coloca primero el 4, y así sucesivamente

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: fijate una libreria que se llama statistics que es sobre estadistica, despues de importarla usa statistics.mode() que es para sacar la moda (el valor que mas se repite de una serie de numeros) Nose bien como ayudarte pero capaz te sirva. Saludos

Comment: ahi vamos mejor.. estas comparando cada elemento con el siguiente solamente.. ahora, vos no queres eso.. vos queres saber si un numero ya aparecio antes.. entonces, que pasa si tomas un numero, y te fijas si esta en otra lista (que vas creando vos) que tenga los numeros que ya pasaron? si esta en esa segunda lista, bingo, es duplicado, no lo agregas a la otra lista..

Comment: Hola, me podrías poner un ejemplo? Gracias

Comment: @gbianchi me podrías poner un ejemplo. Gracias

Comment: que duda particular tenes? te describi el algoritmo.. otro ejemplo es ya el algoritmo terminado ;)

Comment: @gbianchi necesitaría verlo para entenderlo

Comment: El problema es que estás usando el índice `i` al agregar elementos en `duplicados[i] = array[i];`. Pero además tendrías que buscar la manera de que no agregue varias veces los valores duplicados. Para eso puede ser útil la sentencia `break` para salir del segundo ciclo cuando haga falta.

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones devuelves 4,3,1,5 y atendiendo a lo que pides me parece que debería ser 1,4,3,5 ya que el 1 es el primero que se repite?

Comment: @Japv el primer número que encuentras ya repetido es el 4

Comment: @Esther, no entiendo pq es el 4 si empiezas con el 1 y este esta repetido

Comment: @Japv primero recorre el 1, después pasa al 2 y comprueba si ya estaba y como no está repetido pasa al 4, tampoco hay un 4 anteriormente así que pasa al siguiente número que vuelve a ser un 4, comprueba si estaba anteriormente y ve que si había un 4, así que toma ese 4 primero, y así sucesivamente

Comment: @Esther, tu compruebas si el número estaba anteriormente, pero y si compruebas con los números siguientes, te vas a dar cuenta que el primero es 1, pq usas esa forma de comprobar y no otra, en que te basas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi propuesta de algoritmo con el fin de tratar de reducir la complejidad algorítmica es declarar una lista auxiliar que te ayude a saber si el número sobre el que estás iterando ya se encontraba previamente e iría de esta manera:

**Algoritmo**

1. Se recorre el arreglo elemento por elemento
2. Se busca el elemento en la lista auxiliar

   - Si existe se busca el elemento en la lista de duplicados

     - Si no existe en los duplicados se agrega
   - Si no existe se agrega a la lista auxiliar
3. Se elimina la lista auxiliar

**Código**

- Para iterar el arreglo se utiliza un for-each
- Para buscar si lo contiene o no, se utiliza el método [`ArrayList.contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object))
- Para añadir el elemento a la lista se utiliza el método [`ArrayList.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E))
- Para limpiar la lista auxiliar se utiliza el método [`ArrayList.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear())

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5};
        ArrayList<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int number : numbers) {
            if (temp.contains(number)) {
                if (!duplicates.contains(number))
                    duplicates.add(number);
            } else
                temp.add(number);
        }
        
        temp.clear();
        System.out.println(duplicates);

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[4, 3, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Como comentario, no utilicé la Clase [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), dado que los ordena ascendentemente pues implementa la interfaz [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) que a su vez hereda la interfaz [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) es por ello mismo que se debe utilizar esta línea `if (!duplicates.contains(number))`

Comment: Creo que lo que dices no es cierto, HashSet es una implementación de un HashTable, y está implementando un ADT, de hecho en la documentación pone que no hay garantía sobre el orden de los elementos.

Comment: Y SortedSet es la que implementa Set, no al revés

Comment: Cuando hice la prueba con el HashSet, los elementos venían en orden, pues fue mi primera opción. Como se ordenaban y lo vi haciendo debugging, tuve que implementar un ArrayList que simulara la un Set

Answer (score 0):

> me tome un tiempo en descifrarlo, espero te sirva esta solución!

```
public class Numeros_repetidos_array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        

       Numeros_repetidos_array obj=new Numeros_repetidos_array();
       obj.arranque();


    }
       
    
        int array[]={1, 2, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,};
        int duplicados[];
        int numrepetido=0, varduplic=0;
        public void arranque(){
            //asigana mismo tamaño de array principal
            duplicados =new int[array.length];
            comparac();

            for (int i : duplicados) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            mostrararray();
        }
   
        public void mostrararray() {
            //hay una array con muchos 0, y con un valor que se repite
            System.out.println("Los numeros que se repiten son: ");
          //asi que se valida para mostrarlos, si son mayores a 1, se debe imprimir
            for (int i : duplicados) {
               if(i>=1){
                   System.out.print(i+" ");
               }
           }
        }

        public void comparac(){
            //variable boolean para saber si se repite el numero
            boolean serepite=false;
            //doble for para recorrer array principal
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                for(int j=i+1; j<array.length; j++){
                    //se mantiene en falso por cada ciclo, hasta que se compruebe
                    serepite=false;
                    //si el numero coincide con otra posicion en el array
                    if (array[i]==array[j]) {
                        //se verifica en el segundo array si ya se almaceno ese numero
                        for(int k=0; k<duplicados.length;k++){
                            //se compara cad auna de las posiciones del segundo array
                            //si se comprueba que ya existe el numero la variable boolean pasa a ser verdadera
                            if(duplicados[k]==array[j]){
                                serepite=true;
                            }
                        }
                        //al terminar el ciclo for , se compara la variable, si esta estaba repetida en el segundo array
                        //de no ser así, se almacena en la posición donde se encuentra
                        if (serepite==false) {
                            //System.out.println(array[j]);
                            duplicados[i]=array[j];
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: hola, debería de mostrar primero el 4, después el 3, luego el 1, luego el 5, después el 6.

Comment: es decir, primero recorre el array y encuentra un 1, pasa al siguiente y está el 2, y lo compara con el anterior como no está el 2, pasa al siguiente que es el 4 y también lo compara con el anterior y no está, entonces pasa al siguiente que has puesto que es el 5 y tampoco está anteriormente, pasa al siguiente que es un 4 y compara con los números anteriores , aquí sí está repetido el 4, entonces lo toma en un nuevo array, y así sucesivamente